# Error: No Toaster Containers have been initialized to receive toasts

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-toaster

I'm using `angular2-toaster` in my angular 6 app will update it to 9 later using this schema :

```
|___ app.module
|___ shared
     |_______shared.module
     |_______component
             |__________base.component.ts
|___ path
     |_______histograme.component
```

but I'm getting this error `No Toaster Containers have been initialized to receive toasts.`
here is my histograme.component.ts

```
import { BaseComponent } from '../../shared/component/base-component';
export class histograme extends BaseComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
...
error => this.showError(..)
}
...
```

for the baseComponent in which I loaded the ToasterModule and Service

```
import { ToasterService, ToasterConfig } from "angular2-toaster";

@Component({
  template: 
  <toaster-container></toaster-container>
})
export class BaseComponent implements OnDestroy {
protected toasterService: ToasterService;
  protected toasterconfig: ToasterConfig = new ToasterConfig({
    positionClass: 'toast-top-right',
    showCloseButton: true
  });
protected ShowError(){
      this.toasterService.pop('error', 'Erreur', 'message');
}
}
```

my `shared.module` :

```
   imports : [ToasterModule.forRoot()],
   providers: [ToasterService],
   exports: [ToasterModule]
```

app.module

```
   imports : [ToasterModule.forRoot()],
   providers: [ToasterService],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi add this in your html file where you want to show toaster.

```
<toaster-container></toaster-container>


   private toasterService: ToasterService;

    constructor(toasterService: ToasterService) {
        this.toasterService = toasterService;
    }
```

Comment: i add it in my  histograme.component.html but still same error

Comment: i saw you are not making toasterService instance i am modify the answer please check